# No IBAction option for Button in UIContainerView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, delegates, uicontainerview

I have a small Container View (it is a `UITableViewController` with some static cells) embedded within another view.

I am trying to now create an `IBAction` for one of the buttons in the Container View, but when I select one of the cells and control drag into the custom .swift class I have made for it, it only gives me options for creating an Outlet...no option for creating an IB Action.

Is there something I am missing?

PS. I am using Xcode with Swift 1.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cells aren't like buttons. If you want to handle the actions of a cell, use `tableView: didSelectRowAtIndexPath` instead.

Comment: It is a static cell...static cells do not require that normally?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll have to handle cells with `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, even if they're static. Maybe theres another way, I'll have to search a bit though

Comment: I have stupidly mixed up control-dragging segues from static cells with control-dragging to create IBActions and just got totally confused! You are right! No IBActions for cells...need to handle with didSelectRowAtIndexPath :)